# Access visual C# in visual foxpro 9

Tags: visual-foxpro

How do I access visual C# code in visual fox pro 9? I've a code in C# language and need to run it on visual foxpro 9.

Answer (score 0):

Is your C# code in a web service? Visual Foxpro can make calls to XML web services. VFP support for XML Web services is handled through SOAP using WSDL. VFP comes with the SOAP 3.x toolkit.

Here is a good article that demonstrates how to use VFP to call a [XML web service](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/foxpronetwebservices/foxpronetwebservices.asp).